# Encountering an Error in Robot Framework after tests run

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I am new to using Robot Framework, and have run into a problem while running tests on a Jenkins server. The tests are passing, and after the tests run I get the following message:

> Output:  /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Robot Test/workspace/robot/Results/output.xml
>
> [ ERROR ] Reading XML source '/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/Robot Test/workspace/robot/Results/output.xml' failed: ImportError: >No module named expat; use SimpleXMLTreeBuilder instead

I get this message regardless of what tests I run. I am not explicitly calling expat or any other xml module.

I am running Python 2.7.9 and Robot Framework 3.0.

If I run "pybot -o NONE" to cancel the logging the error goes away, but I do want the logging and do not know how to stop the error.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for the error "No module named expat"? You'll find several questions and answers.

Comment: I did look at those, unfortunately, none of them were applicable to my situation, or if they were, I do not know enough to understand how they are. Since I am not using expat, it must be part of Robot. I am already using the Robot Framework plugin for Jenkins, which was the only suggestion from these questions that seemed related.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone who finds this, it appears that my issue was that some of the modules I installed using pip were not installed using "sudo". This led a few of them to install the module, but with errors. When I uninstalled them, and then reinstalled them with sudo, this error has not reappeared.